# omniauth-facebook and testing with rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, omniauth

I am trying to just test omniauth. I have put in config/environments/test.rb

```
OmniAuth.config.test_mode = true
```

and in my spec_helper.rb

```
OmniAuth.config.add_mock(:facebook,
                             { :provider => 'facebook',
                               :uid => '1234567',
                               :info => { :first_name => 'Jonathan', :name=> 'Jonathan', :email => 'jon@jak.com', :image => 'http://graph.facebook.com/1234567/picture?type=square'},
                               :credentials => {
                                 :expires_at => 1351270850,
                                 :token=> 'AAADzk0b791YBAHCNhBI3n6ScmWvuXTY4yIUqXr9WiZCg1R808RYzaHxsHnrbn62IwrIgZCfSBZAVIP6ptF41nm8YtRtZCeBbxbbz1mF8RQZDZD'
                                } })
```

and then in my request controller:

```
it "testing omniauth hash" do
  visit '/auth/facebook'
  request.env["omniauth.auth"][:uid].should == '1234567'
end
```

and get:

```
Failures:

  1) Login logins with the OmniAuth auth hash
     Failure/Error: request.env["omniauth.auth"][:uid].should == '1234567'
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `env' for nil:NilClass
     # ./spec/requests/login_spec.rb:38:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 2.4 seconds
9 examples, 1 failure
```

Any idea what is going on?  thx in advance

**edit 1**
[image]

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: Actually, I reproduced the error and the problem seems to be that the request object doesn't get instantiated unless you issue a native request using [http_verb] [url]. So it should work if you use `get '/auth/facebook'` instead of `visit '/auth/facebook'`.

Comment: thx, but ... hmm... same error. Should   OmniAuth.config.test_mode = true be in the environment file or spec_helper.rb?

Comment: hmmm... still getting the same error. I've added a screenshot above. Not sure but thx for help

Comment: I'm not too familiar with omniauth, but just looking at the railscast on it, it seems that "omniauth.auth" only gets set when the application returns from authenticating, which would explain why `request.env['omniauth.auth']` is coming up nil. Do you try to get around that anywhere else in your code?