# "Real HTTP connections are disabled" error when trying test OmniAuth with RSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I've been trying to test OmniAuth with RSpec, but yet it have not worked.

In `spec_helper.rb`

```
OmniAuth.config.test_mode = true
OmniAuth.config.add_mock(:twitter, {:uid => '12345'})
```

and in `spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb`

```
describe "for signed-in users" do
  before do
    visit "auth/twitter"
  end
  it { should have_content("Log out") }
end
```

And I get following error.

```
 Failure/Error: visit "auth/twitter"
 ActionView::Template::Error:
   Real HTTP connections are disabled. Unregistered request:
```

According to the official document a request to `auth/twitter` should be redirect to `auth/twitter/callback`. Why does it try to have HTTP connection?

I've read following web pages and questions, but I couldn't find why the test failed.

http://blog.zerosum.org/2011/03/19/easy-rails-outh-integration-testing.html
https://github.com/intridea/omniauth/wiki/Integration-Testing
[omniauth-facebook and testing with rspec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12575610/omniauth-facebook-and-testing-with-rspec)
http://blog.plataformatec.com.br/2010/12/acceptance-tests-for-omniauth/

Comment: do you have webmock installed?

Answer (score 11):

As dfedde implies, WebMock blocks HTTP requests in integration tests, but you can either stub the request or call `WebMock.allow_net_connect!` to configure the tests to run as normal.  Check out  [Trying to get selenium working in rails 3 - "WebMock::NetConnectNotAllowedError"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5980856/trying-to-get-selenium-working-in-rails-3-webmocknetconnectnotallowederror) or https://github.com/bblimke/webmock for details.